# PHP: Characteristics of MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

For the one who is thinking of developing a MVC framework, it is important that he understands what it actually is.

So my questions is what are the characteristics of a PHP MVC framework?

Comment: you will find better answers, if you scan SO for the multitude of already answered questions about MVC (php MVC).

Comment: if you search SO for mvc php you'll find a wealth of information!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't restrict the user too much. Build your framework as modules that can interact with eachother, but can also be used seperately.
- Actually, you can only build the V and C parts. The model is something unique to every application. You can add support classes for database access etc, but they are not the model. The model uses them.
- Accept existing technologies such as HTTP. Don't try to banish `?query=parameters` like CakePHP and CodeIgniter do, there's nothing wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

MVC really is easiest to understand by just diving in.  Like aforloney said, I would start with the Wikipedia article, then spend some time skimming through documentation of popular frameworks like Zend, CakePHP, etc.  I've also found [oreilly.com's articles](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html) to be helpful.  Once you understand the basics in theory, pick a framework and start toying around.